# My javascript is running in the console, but returns an error if I run it through html

Tags: javascript, css

I have some javascript code here, that randomly changes the background of the landing page of my website. This is the code:

```
    var bigSize = [ 
                    "url('assets/bg/front1.jpg')",
                    "url('assets/bg/front2.jpg')",
                  ];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 0;
    document.getElementById("front").style.backgroundImage=bigSize[random];
```

When I load the page and take a look at my console, it gives the following error:

```
background.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at background.js:6
```

However, when I run the exact code through the console, the script works perfectly. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `document.getElementById("front")` is `null`. Can you ensure if this element exists on the page **when this script is running**?

Comment: Put the script at the end of the body tag, not before your front element

Comment: You're running that script *before* you define `id="front"`…!?

Comment: DOM is not completely loaded while running that script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that you're inserting the `script` tag before the `body` tag. Insert the `script` tag after the `body` tag. Javascript is not able to find your `element`, it means it hasn't been rendered to the browser yet and when you're accessing it, it is throwing an error.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please upvote and mark as correct if you feel this is right :)